# write something in existing pdf in landscape mode using itextsharp .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I want to write something in an existing pdf.
I have done so far  =>

```
public void certificate()
{
    //get user info using UserId from database
    //UserDetail UserDetail = db.UserDetails.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
    string oldFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/tsms/Certificate/Certificate-of-Completion-Award-Template-Blue.pdf");
    string newFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/tsms/Certificate/newFile.pdf");

    // open the reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 10, 10, 10, 10);
    document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);

    // open the writer
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
    document.Open();

    // the pdf content
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    // select the font properties
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);

    // write the text in the pdf content
    cb.BeginText();
    string text = "Some random blablablabla...";
    // put the alignment and coordinates here
    cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
    cb.EndText();

    // write the text in the pdf content
    cb.BeginText();
    text = "Other random blabla...";
    // put the alignment and coordinates here
    cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
    cb.EndText();

    // create the new page and add it to the pdf
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

    // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
    document.Close();
    fs.Close();
    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

This is working. My problem is: the document I provide `old document` is in landscape mode. I want the new document to be in landscape mode. But this provides me the pdf in portrait mode. So i try.....

update 1 =>

```
document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

This is also not working ..

Also the new text I am adding into old pdf in showing under the old page ...

means -(pdf snapshot below)....
[image: My New Pdf SnapShot]
and my OLD PDF [oldpdfFile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yckfk21k8eaonp/Certificate-of-Completion-Award-Template-Blue.pdf?dl=0) AND NEW PDF (CREATED)-[newpdfFile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xsxs0gqfifaxbw/newFile.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: I'd recommend you use a `PdfStamper` based solution instead of a plain `PdfWriter` based one. That way page rotation is handled more naturally.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your other question ["create new pdf from a old pdf itextsharp .net MVC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215202/create-new-pdf-from-a-old-pdf-itextsharp-net-mvc) I explained why the page appears rotated and how one can counteract that.

Here, though, it becomes quite clear that your task is filling in that certificate. This task should not be implemented by means of a `PdfReader` / `PdfWriter` pair (which is for creating a new document with a copy of one or two pages from some other document) but by a `PdfReader` / `PdfStamper` pair (which is for manipulating existing PDFs, e.g. for form fill-ins).

Using that technique your code could look like this:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile))
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
{
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);

    // write the text in the pdf content
    cb.BeginText();
    string text = "Some random blablablabla...";
    // put the alignment and coordinates here
    cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 640, 520, 0);
    cb.EndText();

    // write the text in the pdf content
    cb.BeginText();
    text = "Other random blabla...";
    // put the alignment and coordinates here
    cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
    cb.EndText();
}
```

resulting in

[image: Screenshot result]